# How to get subchild of child in a xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml that looks like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<crossword1>
    <clues>
        <clue>
         Man's best friend
        </clue>
        <answer>
         dog
        </answer>
        <clue>
         Likes to chase mice
        </clue>
        <answer>
         cat
        </answer>
        <clue>
         Flying mammal
        </clue>
        <answer>
         bat
        </answer>
        <clue>
         Has a trump
        </clue>
        <answer>
         elephant
        </answer>
        <clue>
         Large marsupial
        </clue>
        <answer>
         kangaroo
        </answer>
    </clues>
    <puzzle>
        <acrossClues>
            <clue>Large marsupial</clue>
            <answer>kangaroo</answer>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>5</y>
            <clue>Likes to chase mice</clue>
            <answer>cat</answer>
            <x>2</x>
            <y>7</y>
        </acrossClues>
        <downClues>
            <clue>Has a trump</clue>
            <answer>elephant</answer>
            <x>4</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <clue>Flying mammal</clue>
            <answer>bat</answer>
            <x>1</x>
            <y>4</y>
            <clue>Man's best friend</clue>
            <answer>dog</answer>
            <x>7</x>
            <y>4</y>
        </downClues>

    </puzzle>
    <width>80</width>
    <height>80</height>
    <preview>0</preview>

</crossword1>
```

I want to get only the clues of acrossClues tag (so, the clues childrens of acrossClues).
Until now, I have this:

```
var clues=new Array();
    var xml=loadXMLDoc("data/rebus1.xml");
    var x=xml.getElementsByTagName("acrossClues")[0].childNodes;

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        clues.push(x[i].childNodes.item(0));

    }
    alert(clues[0]);
```

The problem is that alert(clues[0]) gives me null....
why is that?
Thank you.

Comment: `clues` is empty because your're trying to add child nodes of nodes selected to `x` and there are none. Skipping `.childNodes.item(0)` would make more sense, but it still doesn't account for text nodes -- but there's a solution to that already in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `children` instead of `childNodes` because chidlNodes will include text nodes as well and if your xml is formatted then all he continuous white space between the actual element nodes becomes a textnode itself and `xml.getElementsByTagName("acrossClues")[0].childNodes` will have empty text node(s) as well in the collection. So using a [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) will ignore the textnodes.

Try:

```
var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("acrossClues")[0].children;
for (var i = 0, l = x.length; i < l; i++) {
    clues.push(x[i].childNodes.item(0).nodeValue);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sE69t/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question: how can i get only the values of answer tag? I tried something like this x[i].getElementsByTagName("answer")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue but it is not working.I tried other versions also.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    if(x[i].childNodes.item(0) != null){
        clues.push(x[i].childNodes.item(0).nodeValue);
    }

}
```